# Lua - get time and date of specific time zone

Tags: date, datetime, lua, timezone, timezone-offset

I want the time and date of a specific timezone in Lua, formatted in way, `os.date("%a %b %d, %H:%M")` would return it.

I know that `os.date("!%a %b %d, %H:%M")` (added exclamation mark "!") gives me UTC time but how do I move from there and offset the requested time?

In my case the desired timezone is **UTC+08:00**.

Comment: For a complete library see https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[os.date](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date) accepts two parameters:

`os.date ( [format [, time]] )`

The `time` parameter - in seconds - can be used to offset the returned value.

Since `os.time()` returns the current time in seconds, you can simply add your offset (8), multiplied by seconds in a minute (60), multiplied by minutes in a second (60).

```
os.date( "!%a %b %d, %H:%M", os.time() + 8 * 60 * 60 )
```

If you're in UTC+01:00, these are the kinds of output you would receive:

```
> os.date( "%a %b %d, %H:%M")
Wed Mar 16, 09:33
> os.date( "!%a %b %d, %H:%M")
Wed Mar 16, 08:33
> os.date( "!%a %b %d, %H:%M", os.time() + 8 * 60 * 60 )
Wed Mar 16, 16:33
```

If your offset is not by full hours, you have to use a decimal number of course.
For example: **UTC+07:30** would be `7.5` in the equation.

Comment: What about daylight saving time?

Comment: Can't believe that LUA does not have some timezone setting.